# git merge-file flagging whole file as different instead of sections

Tags: git

I'm trying to use `git merge-file` for a 3 way merge between two branches (`current` and `other`) that diverged long ago file by file. I chose this approach because doing a `git merge`would result in way too many conflicts and would make it a nightmare, whereas doing on a file by file bases won't break everything so much and updating all tests as I go with the changes would be easier.

The idea then is to use this script that takes a branch name, a file name and performes the merge using the last version of the file on the current branch, the version from point of divergence and the version from the last commit on the other branch.

The problem is that instead of highlighting only the sections that are different this command is simply saying that the whole file diverged, even if in reality only a few lines are different. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash

common_sha=$(git merge-base HEAD $1)

git show $common_sha:$2 > common
git show $1:$2 > theirs

git merge-file --diff3 $2 common theirs

rm common
rm theirs
```

Here's an example of the script being used:

```
$ git branch -a
* current_branch
  master
  other_branch
$ my_merge.sh other_branch file.txt
```

Here's the files it used

`common version of file.txt`

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

`current branch's version of file.txt`

```
line 1
line 2.2
line 3
line 4.1
line 6
```

`other branch's version of file.txt`

```
line 1
line 2.1
line 2.2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

And the expected vs actual result

`expected result after running the script`

```
line 1
<<<<<<< file.txt
line 2.2
||||||| common
line 2
=======
line 2.1
line 2.2
>>>>>>> theirs
line 3
line 4.1
line 6
```

`actual result`

```
<<<<<<< file.txt
line 1
line 2.2
line 3
line 4.1
line 6
||||||| common
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
=======
line 1
line 2.1
line 2.2
line 3
line 4
line 5
>>>>>>> theirs
```

Comment: is there an EOL-format change involved?

Comment: I don't know, how do I check that? But I think there shouldn't be since this example was made using the same terminal, same machine, same configs on a span of 5 min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check with file:

```
git show HEAD:a-file > a.txt
git show $1:a-file > b.txt # replace $1 for the revision you are playing with
git show $( git merge-base HEAD $1 ):a-file > c.txt
```

Use file on them (`file a.txt b.txt c.txt`) and check what the value is for each to see if they are all one format (CRLF or LF) or if they change between CRLF and LF... or you could open all 3 on a decent text editor that could show you the format (unix/windows). If they are  mixed, that's why you are seeing that problem.

Comment: You sir, is a life saver and I feel very dumb now. Any recommendations on how to setup git so that it keeps line endings consistent?

Comment: Git has a few tricks under its leave to handle EOL.... and they are a pain in the ass to play with. The best you can do is to tell git not to mess with them and just let developers take care of it. Just add a line like this in .gitarributes: `* -text`. Have the file as part of the project so that everybody shares it.